# Assigning value to select by patching a form

Tags: angular

I have this select:

```
<select class="form-select form-select-md" formControlName="MaritalStatus">
    <option value="0" selected>Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of maritalStatusList" [ngValue]="option">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I have a list, which is what I'm using for the options. Then, the selected option I save it in the form by means of the formControlName. I'm using ngValue because option is an object, and I want to store the whole object instead of just the ID. It works fine, but when I try to patch the value the selected value is not appearing in the select.

I patch a whole bunch of values at the same time, but this is basically what it would look like:

```
this.form.patchValue({ MaritalStatus: MaritalStatus });
```

And the MaritalStatus object I would be patching would look like this:

```
export class MaritalStatus {
    id: number;
    name: string = '';
    createdAt: string = '';
    updatedAt: string = '';
    deletedAt: string = '';
}
```

What I want to accomplish is that when I patch that MaritalStatus object, it appears selected in the select, whose list of options is a list of MaritalStatuses. I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix it with a solution that I don't like so much, but so far it is the only thing that worked. What I did was that I looked for the object that contains the ID that I wanted to patch inside the list. So assume that `ms` is the MaritalStatus object that I want to patch.

```
this.form.patchValue({ MaritalStatus: this.maritalStatusList.find(x => x.id === ms.id) })
```

And it is working perfectly. I'm not sure why directly patching the value isn't working, as it saves me that `find`, but I'll go with that until I find something better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a compareWith function :

```
<select class="form-select form-select-md" formControlName="MaritalStatus"  [compareWith]="compareFn" >
```

and in your .ts file (adapt as required ) :

```
compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean { 
    return c1 && c2 &&( c1.id === c2.id || c2 === c1.id);
 }
```